# Devexpress gridview cell value not appear immediately

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface, gridview, devexpress

I have created an event handler to display data based on user selected value.

```
private void gridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.CellValueChangedEventArgs e)
{
        DataRow dataRow = gridView1.GetDataRow(e.RowHandle);
       //Did some query to get firstDataRow
        dataRow["UOM"] = firstDataRow["SalesUOM"].ToString();
        dataRow["Description"] = firstDataRow["Description"].ToString();
        dataRow["Desc2"] = firstDataRow["Desc2"].ToString();
        dataRow["FurtherDescription"] = firstDataRow["FurtherDescription"].ToString();
        dataRow["Qty"] = 1;
        dataRow["UnitPrice"] = AutoCount.Converter.ToDecimal(firstDataRow["Price"]);
        dataRow["UnitCost"] = AutoCount.Converter.ToDecimal(firstDataRow["Cost"]);
}
```

The problem is the value does not appear immediately, but only appear after the user click outside the row. If the value does not appear but save operation is carried out, the value will be save in database, proving the data is there but does not displayed out in the interface.

[image: When the value first changed]
[image: After user click outside the row, value displayed]

Comment: You may need to invoke the GridView's UpdateCurrentRow method after you make your changes: https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.ColumnView.UpdateCurrentRow

Comment: Hi Brendon, I have tried but it doesn't work. I have used breakpoints to troubleshoot the code and I just found out the gridView_CellValueChanged event only triggers after user have leave the row. Is it a way to work around it?